# why finishedWithAuth: method didn't call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

[image]

I done google integration on my sample app, while i am trying to implement in my project the finishedWithAuth method didn't call.

0.its entering into google+ login screen.

1.i done creating Oauth client key generation.

2.Added gppsigninbutton.

3.in appdelegate.m file

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
   if([FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance])
   {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"entering");
        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
   }


}
```

implemented

4. url also added in .plist.

*this is my code*

```
      signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    //signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

    // You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    //    signIn.clientID=APIID;
    signIn.homeServerClientID = kClientId;
    // Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
    //    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope
//    signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope
        signIn.scopes=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,kGTLAuthScopePlusMe, nil];
    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"


    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
}
- (void)signOut {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    if(error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *serverCode = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;
        NSLog(@"this is server code%@",serverCode);
        NSLog(@"user email%@", signIn.authentication.userEmail);
        NSLog(@"user id%@",signIn.authentication.userID);
        NSLog(@"auth token=%@",auth.accessToken);
        NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%@",auth.accessToken];
        NSString* escapedUrl = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedUrl]];
        NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
        NSData *data = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];



        NSLog(@"this is jsonvalues==%@",json);
        if ( auth.userEmail)
        {
            [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:[GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"] completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
             {
                 // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",person.image.url]];
                 // NSLog(@"%@",url);
                 //  NSLog(@"Name:%@",person.displayName);
                 //                 NSLog(@"birthday:%@",person.birthday);
                 //
                 //                 NSLog(@"gender:%@",person.gender);
                 NSLog(@"peoplelist%@",person.displayName);
                 NSLog(@"peopleimae=%@",person);
                 //                 NSLog(@"people image%@",person.image);
                 //                 NSLog(@"people emailid%@",person.emails);
                 //                  imgurl = userData[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
                 NSDictionary *dic=(NSDictionary *)person;
                 if(person.image)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"this is converted dictionary=%@",dic);
                 }
             }];
//            [self disconnect];
        }
    }
}
- (void)disconnect {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
}
- (void)didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Received error %@", error);
    } else {
        // The user is signed out and disconnected.
        // Clean up user data as specified by the Google+ terms.
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: add some more code ....

Comment: which area of code you want bro... @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro any problem with clientID

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro as per your suggestion i have added pictures what i was accessing..

Comment: means your code works , only call back is not work

Comment: @KishoreKumar the problem seems to be `signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES`. Remove that line and change to `signIn.scopes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail, nil];`. Then try.

Comment: @RoOmin changed but same problem arising ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using both `Facebook` and `Google+` Sign In. So change your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {


    NSString *stringURL = [ url absoluteString];
    if([stringURL containsString:@"fb"])
    {

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
    }
    else
    {
        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                             annotation:annotation];

    }
}
```

Also code for loginWithGoogle should look like the following. The problem is with your `signIn.scopes`.

```
-(IBAction)loginWithGooglePressed:(id)sender
{
    ///
    signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;

    //signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

    signIn.scopes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail, nil];

    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;

    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

}
```

Works Fine for me:

[image: Works fine For Me]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the URL Schemes from `info.plist` in question?

Comment: bro my above code working in my sample project ,while i try to implement it in myproject its didn't call what to do....?